# Create a line on polyline type m

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

in QGIS I have a layer "HlavniInfo" which is polyline type m. HlavniInfo is a layer which contains a list of roads - ID, name, from, to, length ...

Then I have a second table that contains the widths of the road: in each row there is an ID from the MainInfo, FROM whose station is the width, TO which station is the width, the value of the width - example:

MainInfo - the length of road ID 1725 is 1000 meters
Width table:

```
ID 1725; FROM 0; TO 100; WIDHTS 3.6
ID 1725; FROM 100; TO 250; WIDHTS 4.5
ID 1725; FROM 250; TO 1000; WIDHTS 3.8
```

I need to draw in QGIS 3 lines according to the records in the WIDTH table. Ideally, if the FROM or TO or WIDTH record in the table changes (externally by editing) and the update ...

Furthermore, it is possible to use the UI form, after clicking on the road ID, to display in the form all the records in the WIDTH table that correspond to the road ID? Maybe in the next tab of the form?

I tried routing, substring, but nothing helped.

Comment: Since I don't know exactly how the data is structured, a definitive answer is impossible. In your example, after all, a polyline has one road line per ID, and WIDTH has the width from where to where on each road. The question is, how do I know which point on the polyline is the starting point? If you don't know this, it's an unsolvable problem. Anyway, if you know the starting point of each line, you can use the distance from the starting point of the line to separate the lines and then enter the width value.

Comment: I think I know the starting point for each line. Which tool will I use to make that last sentence? Alternatively, I can upload a sample data somewhere.